# Combo box re-arranging numbers 1-30 in c#

Tags: c#

I have been trying to implement a combobox that will list number of 1 - 30 sequentially but it keeps on re-arranging unsequentially() when the application loads. I have exhausted my options.

Below are the code I have tried out of numerous other ones:

Method 1:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 30; i++)
{
   string[] numbers = { i.ToString() };
   cmbYOWE.Items.AddRange(numbers);
}
```

Method 2:

```
cmbYOWE.Items.AddRange(System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(i => (object)i).ToArray());
```

where cmbYOWE is the code name of my combobox control.

Sequential order should be like this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 and so on
but instead, it's arranging it like this: 1 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 2, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24 and so on

Comment: Why are you storing these values as strings (and sorting them as such) when you want them sorted in numeric order. Change the declaration numbers to int[] instead (without casting as objects) and that will solve your issues.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem, both with the question and the accepted answer, is that it is something completely different from the code and suggested solution. Good that the problem was solved for OP but as it stands this question and answer has no value for future visitors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a different issue. You might be using threads/Ajax code in your application which is disturbing the order.

Anyway, expanding your method 2, if sorting is allowed, can you try this.

```
var numbers = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(1, 30).Select(i (object)i).ToArray();
Array.Sort(numbers);
comboBox1.Items.AddRange(numbers);
comboBox1.Sorted = false;
```

Comment: it's still the same problem.

Comment: Are you using the combobox anywhere else? Also, is there threading in your application?

Comment: Check if Combobox.sorted = true. If yes, set it to false.

Comment: I could replicate the issue when I added Combox.sorted = true to my code. If this is true, it tries to put the added element in its sorted position and because the items are objects and numbers, the sorting order is going wrong. Make Combobox.Sorted = false if you want the elements to be added one after the other. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.sorted(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks Priyanka, the sorted property was true, so I changed it to false and it's working now. Can you add me up on skype? My skype name is key4math

Comment: you have not added me on skype

Answer (score 0):

Just try this one. It's simple!

```
for (int i = 1; i < 31; i++)
{
    cmbYOWE.Items.Add(i.ToString());
}
```

Comment: can you help me look at the application, my skype name is key4math.......my email is princeolatjohnjoe@yahoo.com